# Postgresql extension Makefile returning error

Tags: postgresql, makefile

I wrote a SQL extension following the instructions on [PGXN](http://manager.pgxn.org/howto), but I always get a make install error as following:

```
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.5/extension'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 .//myextname.control '/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 .//sql/myextname--1.0.0.sql .//sql/myextname--1.0.0.sql  '/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/'
/usr/bin/install: will not overwrite just-created ‘/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/myextname--1.0.0.sql’ with ‘.//sql/myextname--1.0.0.sql’
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

My Makefile is as following:

```
EXTENSION    = myextname
EXTVERSION   = $(shell grep default_version $(EXTENSION).control | \
               sed -e "s/default_version[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*'\([^']*\)'/\1/")

DATA         = $(filter-out $(wildcard sql/*--*.sql),$(wildcard sql/*.sql))
TESTS        = $(wildcard test/sql/*.sql)
REGRESS      = $(patsubst test/sql/%.sql,%,$(TESTS))
REGRESS_OPTS = --inputdir=test
DOCS         = $(wildcard doc/*.md)
MODULES      = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard src/*.c))
PG_CONFIG    = pg_config
PG91         = $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --version | grep -qE " 8\\.| 9\\.0" && echo no || echo yes)

ifeq ($(PG91),yes)
all: sql/$(EXTENSION)--$(EXTVERSION).sql

sql/$(EXTENSION)--$(EXTVERSION).sql: $(strip sql/tables.sql \
        sql/types.sql \
        sql/domains.sql \
    )
    cat $^ > $@

DATA            = $(wildcard sql/*--*.sql) sql/$(EXTENSION)--$(EXTVERSION).sql
EXTRA_CLEAN = sql/$(EXTENSION)--$(EXTVERSION).sql
endif

PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

[This blog](https://blog.pgaddict.com/posts/why-pgxn-distribution-tests-fail) says this error is caused by this line:

```
DATA = $(wildcard sql/*--*.sql) sql/$(EXTENSION)--$(EXTVERSION).sql
```

which evaluates into the same filename twice (and /usr/bin/install refuses to overwrite the first instance of the file).

But how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have copied the `Makefile` from PGXN, and it is probably much more complicated than you need.

For example, do you target PostgreSQL versions below 9.1?

You'll be much better off with a small, simple custom tailored `Makefile` like this:

```
MODULES = src/myextname
EXTENSION = myextname
DATA = sql/myextname--1.0.sql
DOCS = doc/myextname.md
REGRESS = myextname
REGRESS_OPTS = --inputdir=test

PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

This (untested) `Makefile` sticks with the file organization suggested by PGXN.